# React DevTools show very big background when moving cursor to a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-devtools

Chrome Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (x86_64)

React Developer Tools
4.10.1 (12/4/2020)

Installed the React Developer Tools extension for the Chrome browser.

- open a website which is developed by React tech (e.g. https://react-dev-inspector.zthxxx.me/ can be used to have a try)
- open Chrome menu ... => More tools => Developer Tools
- go to tab "Component" if the current page is loaded with the React component.
- in the left-top corner of the tab page, there is a cursor button with tooltips: "select an element in the page to inspect", click it and then move the mouse to the web page.
- it will show you the React component with a tooltip. (just like the following screenshot)
- the "More" button is a HTML element "a" with size 66px x 40px.

[image: the normal status]

But my problem is that on the website we developed, the React inspect will show with a very big black background. like the screenshot below.

- it is a button with size 240px x 52px
- but the location of the tip is not beside the component, it is on the top of the screen
- and there is a very big background

I am not sure where/what configures we set incorrectly.

Any comment and help will be much appreciated.

[image: my website with problems]

Comment: Have you found a solution by any chance? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured what was wrong in my case. Maybe it will help someone.

I had a global css rule that caused expanding the div's added by react dev tools. in my case it was something like that:

```
div:not([class]) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Unfortunately, at the this point in time, there is no way to specifically target dynamically added container as it has no id, class or attribute.